# When JS diverges based on value of select option, does your JS check options exactly or?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given some html:

```
<select id="this">
  <option value="a"></option>
  <option value="b"></option>
</select>
```

If your JS does different things depending on which option was selected, I'm wondering, how "strict" are you in the comparison? I.e., how paranoid are you? So there's a spectrum of options:

```
// OPTION A - not very paranoid

select_value = $("#this").val()
if (select_value == "a") {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}

// OPTION B - more paranoid, strict ===, but also has another else jus tin case

select_value = $("#this").val()
if (select_value === "a") {
  ...
} else if (select_value === "b") {
  ...
} else {
  // some kind of exception handling, e.g., an error alert pops up, in case somehow user sneaks in another value...
}
```

Just asking because I realized I constantly default toward the most paranoid solution ever for everything, which is likely unhealthy for me and my code.

Comment: So... Your coding question is? Because this is not the right place to discuss your possible paranoia.

Answer (score 2):

In the question's example there's no need for paranoia. `==` will sufice.

`===` is used when you want to check equality based on value AND type of the var.

`==` allows for implicit conversion of the compared vars.

So `'1' == 1` is true,  `'1' === 1` is false.

As you're just checking the select's value there's no need for `===`

P.S.: Are you a Black Sabbath fan or something ? if yes leave the paranoias to Ozzy. He's good with them. :D

Comment: If the answer was helpful please accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: in a 2 option scenario, would you do `if/ else-if/ else`, to capture all the potential options and further catch exceptions, or just an `if/else` situation with one option?

Comment: depends on the case... provide an exact case and I'll answer you. In other question of course, because this is on hold. Or rephrase the question to fit the rules (ask a non-opininated question that can have an exact answer)